# Run HTML page in background for a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am busy writing a chrome extension. Is it possible for me to run a HTML page in the background of a web page? Why would I want to do this? Well, I am injecting CSS into a page using a js file linked to my popup.html.

It does inject the CSS automatically, but only if I click on the icon that opens the pop up. So, can I open that popup automatically each time a page loads in the background? So the CSS is injected automatically when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red.zip

^^ does similar job. There are chrome background scripts. Check out their APIs. BTW JS runs in the background, not HTML.